# Best ways to scrape website repeatedly

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, python-requests

I would like to extract data from a website that contains prices for connections, such as an airline's website. They do not have an API. **I would like to have the tool fill in the form on the page** with date, time, departure, destination. After this, the form has to be submitted and then results are displayed. I want to scrape the date for the different options and repeat the same process with different values for data, time, etc but on the same page.

I have read around and found out about Scrapy but I am not sure whether it is a little over the top for this purpose since I do not need a crawler but just want to scrape the same page many times. 
Beautifulsoup&Requests also seems to be a good combination. Since I do only have experience with Selenium, I wonder what is the best solution for my purpose? **I am looking for a Python-based solution.**

Comment: I would take a look at Selenium!  It will allow you to script filling out the form on the website and you can parse out the results from there.

Comment: I have used Selenium, but I am looking for something on a larger scale. If possible, a tool that can make multiple requests at once.

Comment: Wrap selenium in multiple threads...

Comment: You may also want to look at [scrapy cloud](https://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud) which can make managing many spiders easier. You can also build simple scrapy spiders visually with [Portia](https://scrapinghub.com/portia).

Comment: As written, this question is too opinion based.  If you were to focus on more objective criteria and rather than ask people to choose a tool for you, ask how the tools compare on stated criteria that matter to you, the answers might be objective enough to be on-topic

Comment: My criteria would be that I do not want to be blocked from that site, so my scraper should immediate real users, maybe even use VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup & Requests are a simple solution to this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


def get_soup(url=None, data=None):

    r = requests.post(url, data=data)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    return soup


def scraper(soup):

    # Write your code to scrape the information you need from the page

    return data


def main(url=None, data=None):

    soup = get_soup(url, data)

    data_you_want = scraper(soup)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    url = 'www.somewebsite.com'

    datas = [{'form_name_1': 'form_input_1', 'form_name_2': 'form_input_2', ...}, {'form_name_1': 'form_input_1', ...]

    # Time to wait between each scrape
    wait_time = 5

    for data in datas:
        main(url, data)
        time.sleep(wait_time)
```

***Note that websites like an airline website may block scrapers